# Distribution of Cauchy RV Conditional on Sum with Something Else

Tags: probability, density-function

I have $S=R+\epsilon$ where $R \sim Cauchy(r, 1/\alpha)$ and $\epsilon \sim Cauchy(0, 1/\beta)$. I want to calculate the distribution of $R$ given $S=s$.

I've tried the following:

By the definition of conditional probability, we have $f_{R | s}(x | s) = \frac{f_R(x) f_\epsilon(s-x)}{f_{R+\epsilon}(s)}$.

We know that for $X \sim Cauchy (x_0, \gamma)$ we have the density function
$f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi \gamma} \frac{\gamma^2}{(x-x_0)^2 + \gamma^2}$

Then plugging this in (and simplifying a bit), we get

$$f_{R | s}(x | s) = \frac{1}{\pi (\frac{1}{\alpha + \beta})}
\frac{\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}}{\frac{((x-r)^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2})((s-x)^2+\frac{1}{\beta^2})}{(x-r)^2+(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha \beta})^2
}
}
$$

I can't simplify the part on the bottom to get what would be desired if it were a Cauchy distribution. Any hints/tips? Thank you!

Comment: Just use the fact that sum of two Cauchy distributions is another Cauchy with new location and scale sum of the old ones.

Comment: A.S.--thanks for your help, but I'm already using that fact. I can't seem to get the distribution of one conditional on the sum. Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem (you should fix the formatting in your post)? You have a product of two Cauchy pdf's over another cauchy pdf. It's not going to be Cauchy.

Comment: There's no chance it will be Cauchy ( something, 1/(alpha+beta))?

Comment: That's true for normals (and possible normals only) but not for Cauchy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any intuition or reason?

Comment: I will reverse the question: why do you expect the conditional to stay in the same family? That seems like a rather restricting property for the family of distributions you are considering. It's true if you consider uniforms, for example, but uniforms are not stable distributions as Cauchy and normal are (among which normal might be the only one). (Sidenote: you seem to be using the inverse of the commonly used scale parameter which is a tad confusing).

Comment: Thanks a lot AS. And yes, I know I'm using the inverse.